# sbt deletes resources under classes folder of other scala versions

Tags: sbt

I'm building an `sbt` project with these settings:

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.11.8", "2.12.8"),
```

When compiling, sbt copies resource files to the `classes/` output folder.
However, **the resource files for other scala versions than the current one get deleted** somehow. That's unexpected, especially because **the compiled `.class` files remain for both versions**.

I tried to enable -v for verbose & -d for debug, but still can't see why/where the resources get deleted from the other version's `classes/`.

```
sbt +mleap-spark-extension/compile -d -v
```

> [debug] Copy resource mappings:
>   [debug]   (/Users/juhoautio/ideaprojects/mleap/mleap-spark-extension/src/main/resources/reference.conf,/Users/juhoautio/ideaprojects/mleap/mleap-spark-extension/target/scala-2.11/classes/reference.conf)
>
> debug] Copy resource mappings:
>   [debug]   (/Users/juhoautio/ideaprojects/mleap/mleap-spark-extension/src/main/resources/reference.conf,/Users/juhoautio/ideaprojects/mleap/mleap-spark-extension/target/scala-2.12/classes/reference.conf)

Then:

```
find mleap-spark-extension/target -name reference.conf
```

Finds only the last one, ie.:

> mleap-spark-extension/target/scala-2.12/classes/reference.conf

However, both `target/scala-2.12/classes/` and `target/scala-2.11/classes/` still have the compiled `.class` files. It's just the resource file that gets lost.

---

Also if I only build with 2.11 after that:

```
sbt mleap-spark-extension/compile -d -v && find mleap-spark-extension/target -name reference.conf
```

Then:

```
find mleap-spark-extension/target -name reference.conf
```

Finds only the last one, ie.:

> mleap-spark-extension/target/scala-2.11/classes/reference.conf

---

This is with `sbt.version = 0.13.18`. This might've changed in newer versions, but upgrading is not trivial, so I'm trying to at least find out why this happens with the current version.

**How could I debug this further? Ideally I would want sbt to not touch the other scala version's `classes/` folder at all!**

Comment: Maybe you could change the owner / permissions of the files in such a way that the user running SBT cannot delete the files, and hope that is blows up with a stacktrace...

Comment: @cbley Interesting idea! Unfortunately sbt silently ignored the fact that it was unable to delete the file. I couldn't find anything new in the output. When I remove write permission to the `reference.conf` I found it in both 2.11 & 2.12 after compile.